# Trouble with applying a nested loop on a list

Tags: r

I have a list consisting of 3 elements:

```
datalist=list(a=datanew1,b=datanew2,c=datanew3)
```

datalist$a :

```
      Inv_ret Firm size  leverage        Risk  Liquidity Equity
17  0.04555968  17.34834 0.1323199 0.011292273 0.02471489      0
48  0.01405835  15.86315 0.6931730 0.002491093 0.12054914      0
109 0.04556252  16.91602 0.1714068 0.006235836 0.01194579      0
159 0.04753472  14.77039 0.3885720 0.007126830 0.06373028      0
301 0.03941040  16.94377 0.1805346 0.005450653 0.01723319      0
```

datalist$b :

```
      Inv_ret Firm size   leverage        Risk  Liquidity      Equity
31  0.04020832  18.13300 0.09326265 0.015235240 0.01579559 0.005025379
62  0.04439078  17.84086 0.11016402 0.005486982 0.01266566 0.006559096
123 0.04543250  18.00517 0.12215307 0.011154742 0.01531451 0.002282790
173 0.03960613  16.45457 0.10828643 0.011506857 0.02385191 0.009003780
180 0.03139643  17.57671 0.40063094 0.003447233 0.04530395 0.000000000
```

datalist$c :

```
   Inv_ret Firm size   leverage       Risk   Liquidity      Equity
92  0.03081029  19.25359 0.10513159 0.01635201 0.025760806 0.000119744
153 0.03280746  19.90229 0.11731517 0.01443786 0.006769735 0.011999005
210 0.04655847  20.12543 0.11622403 0.01418010 0.003125632 0.003802365
250 0.03301018  20.67197 0.13208234 0.01262499 0.009418828 0.021400052
282 0.04355975  20.03012 0.08588316 0.01918129 0.004213846 0.023657440
```

I am trying to create a `cor.test` on the `datalist` above :

```
Cor.tests=sapply(datalist,function(x){ 
  for(h in 1:length(names(x))){

    for(i in 1:length(names(x$h[i]))){
      for(j in 1:length(names(x$h[j]))){
      cor.test(x$h[,i],x$h[,j])$p.value 


    }}}})
```

But I get an `error` :

```
Error in cor.test.default(x$h[, i], x$h[, j]) : 
  'x' must be a numeric vector
```

Any suggestions about what I am doing wrong?

P.S. If I simply have one dataframe, `datanew1` :

```
      Inv_ret Firm size  leverage        Risk  Liquidity Equity
17  0.04555968  17.34834 0.1323199 0.011292273 0.02471489      0
48  0.01405835  15.86315 0.6931730 0.002491093 0.12054914      0
109 0.04556252  16.91602 0.1714068 0.006235836 0.01194579      0
159 0.04753472  14.77039 0.3885720 0.007126830 0.06373028      0
301 0.03941040  16.94377 0.1805346 0.005450653 0.01723319      0
```

I use this `loop` :

```
results=matrix(NA,nrow=6,ncol=6)
for(i in 1:length(names(datanew1))){
  for(j in 1:length(names(datanew1))){
    results[i,j]<-cor.test(datanew1[,i],datanew1[,j])$p.value 


}}
```

And the output is:

```
results :
             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]        [,6]
[1,] 0.000000e+00 7.085663e-09 3.128975e-10 3.018239e-02 4.806400e-10 0.475139526
[2,] 7.085663e-09 0.000000e+00 2.141581e-21 0.000000e+00 2.247825e-20 0.454032499
[3,] 3.128975e-10 2.141581e-21 0.000000e+00 2.485924e-25 2.220446e-16 0.108643838
[4,] 3.018239e-02 0.000000e+00 2.485924e-25 0.000000e+00 5.870007e-15 0.006783324
[5,] 4.806400e-10 2.247825e-20 2.220446e-16 5.870007e-15 0.000000e+00 0.558827862
[6,] 4.751395e-01 4.540325e-01 1.086438e-01 6.783324e-03 5.588279e-01 0.000000000
```

Which is exactly what I want. But I want to get 3 matrices, one for each element of the `datalist` above.

`EDIT`:
If I do as Joran says:

```
Cor.tests=lapply(datalist,function(x){ 

  results=matrix(NA,nrow=6,ncol=6)
  for(i in 1:length(names(x))){
    for(j in 1:length(names(x))){
      results[i,j]<-cor.test(x[,i],x[,j])$p.value 
    }}})
```

I get:

```
$a
NULL

$b
NULL

$c
NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without `for` loops.

1) A solution with base R:

```
lapply(datalist,
       function(datanew) outer(seq_along(datanew),
                               seq_along(datanew),
                               Vectorize(function(x, y)
                                            cor.test(datanew[ , x],
                                                     datanew[ , y])$p.value)))
```

2) A solution with the package `psych`:

```
library(psych)
lapply(datalist, function(datanew) corr.test(datanew)$p)
```

---

A modified version of approach in the question:

```
lapply(datalist, function(x) { 
                    results <- matrix(NA,nrow=6,ncol=6)
                    for(i in 1:6){
                       for(j in 1:6){
                          results[i,j]<-cor.test(x[,i],x[,j])$p.value 
                       }
                    }
                    return(results)
                 })
```

There were two major problems in these commands:

1. The matrix `results` was not returned. I added `return(results)`
   to the function.
2. You want to have a 6 by 6 matrix whereas your data frames have
       seven columns. I replaced `1:length(names(x))` with `1:6` in the
       `for` loops.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution Sven! But I am trying to understand why the `lapply` solution in my question does not work. `datalist` is of length 3. Therefore, I am trying to create a list of length 3, where each element is `cor.test` for the 3 elements of `datalist`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks Sven! Great answer! But my data.frames has only 6 columns though.

Comment: By the way Sven, do you have some blog about R? If you do, please give me the link, because I would love to read it!:)

Comment: @user1665355 I don't have a blog. But if I start a blog, I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to attempt to provide you with working code, but hopefully what follows will help explain why what you're trying isn't working.

Let's look at the first few lines of your `sapply` call:

```
Cor.tests=sapply(datalist,function(x){ 
  for(h in 1:length(names(x))){
    for(i in 1:length(names(x$h[i]))){
```

Let's stop here and think for a moment about `x$h[i]`. At this points, `x` is the argument passed to your anonymous function in `sapply` (presumably either a data frame or matrix, I can't be sure from your question which it is).

At this point in your code, what is `h`? `h` is the index variable in the previous `for` loop, so initially `h` has the value 1.  The `$` operator is for selecting items from an object by *name*. Is there something in `x` named `h`? I think not.

But then things get even worse as you attempt to select the `i`th element within this non-existant thing named `h` inside `x`. I'm honestly not even sure what R's interpreter will do with that since you're referencing the variable `i` in the expression that is supposed to define the range of values for `i`. Circular, anyone?

If you simply remove all attempts at the third for loop, you should have more luck. Just take the working version, plop it down in the body of the anonymous function, and replace every occurrence of `datanew1` with `x`.

Good luck.

(PS - You might want be happier with the output of `lapply` rather than `sapply`)

Comment: I tried it joran by I get `null` answer for the `datalist` elements...What am I missing?